# How to design DTO classes for nested domain objects?

Tags: automapper, dto

I am new to using DTOs.

I have two domain classes:

1. Category
2. Product

as follows

```
public class Category
{
    // Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties
    public virtual Category ParentCategory { get; set; }

    // Foreign key
    public int? ParentCategoryId { get; set; }

    // Collections
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Category> Subcategories { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    // Properties
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Navigation property
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

    // Foreign key
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use Automapper.

I am not sure how to design DTOs for the above aggregate (graph).

- Should `CategoryDTO` have a collection of type `ProductDTO` or a collection of type `Product`?
- Should `ProductDTO` have a `CategoryDTO` as navigation property or a `Category` or just an Id to the `Category`?

Can anyone suggest the code for DTOs?
How should this structure be flattened (if it should) and mapped to domain classes?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: You create DTOs for a purpose. The purpose defines the content of the DTO. So this can only be answered if we know what you need the DTOs for.

Comment: I want to decouple presentation layer of an MVC Web appliction from domain classes by using DTOs as ViewModels.

Comment: Here DTOs would be used to pass objects to business layer and from there to data layer for CRUD operations on Category and Products in admin panel of the Website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I design my DTOs to be only the data used for a specific controller action for MVC. Typically this means if I have a CategoryController, then I have a CategoryIndexModel, CategoryDetailsModel, CategoryEditModel etc etc. Only include the information you want on that screen. I flatten as much as I can, I don't create child DTOs unless I have a Partial or collection.

Comment: So collections in my code sample should be `ICollection<ProductDTO>`, right?